# Strange Output while combining files

Tags: python, file

For the output, I want a list with each index containing a number and a letter combined from two different files such as B2. Instead, when I run my program I get output listing each files values on a different line. One of the input files is a simple list of numbers and the other is a list of letters. Based on my code, I am hoping to get some help. Thanks in advance!

```
def combine():
    mylist = []
    galaxy = open("galaxies.rtf","r")
    print("Reading from galaxies.txt...")
    for line in galaxy:
        gline = galaxy.read()
    cycle = open("cycles.rtf","r")
    print("Reading from cycle.txt...")
    for line in cycle:
        cline = cycle.read()
    print("Combining values...")
    string = gline + cline
    mylist.append(string)
    galaxy.close()
    cycle.close()
    return mylist
combine()

# the main function calls combine() to read the data from files
# then displays a formatted table with the combined values
def main():
#Print a header at start of main() function
    print("Report of BOOYA Radio Galaxy Observations\n")
 # Call the combine() function, returned list saved as radioData
    radioData = combine()
# Loop through the radioData list printing 5 columns of values
    for j in range(0,len(radioData),5):
        for k in range(0,5):
            print(radioData[j+k],end="\t")
        print()
main()
```

Comment: Please edit your question so the python indentation is correct. And what is some of the content of the input file?

Comment: Please show us an example of your input files and your expected output if you want that we can help you.

Comment: Fixed the indentation. One of the input files was a list of numbers while the other was a list of letters. The purpose of the program is to combine the two, for example, B5.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems. For instance, this

```
for line in galaxy:
    gline = galaxy.read()
```

reads one line from `galaxy` and puts it in `line`, then reads the rest of the file to its end and puts it in `gline`. On the second round, the file has no more content so the for exits.

You can do the work a different ways. Files iterate lines including the `\n`. `zip` takes multiple iterators and combines them into tuples. You can use that to iterate the lines from both files, strip the line endings and add them together.

```
>>> with open('galaxies.rtf') as f1, open('cycles.rtf') as f2:
...     mylist = list((l1.strip() + l2.strip() for l1, l2 in zip(f1, f2)))
... 
>>> mylist
['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4', 'E5', 'F6']
```

This may still be a problem because `rtf` aren't simple text files.